# PHP Form select & radio error

Tags: php

PHP Form select & radio error
I have a form, but I got php error on select button and radio button
the error I got are $age and $gender

how to print error message in same page?

here is php code

```
$firstname="";  $lastname="";   $email="";  $re_email="";

if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $firstname=strip_tags($_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname=strip_tags($_POST['lastname']);
    $email=strip_tags(strtolower($_POST['email']));
    $re_email=strip_tags(strtolower($_POST['re_email']));
    $password=strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $re_password=strip_tags($_POST['re_password']);
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    $gender=$_POST['gender'];
    $date=date("Y-m-d");

    if($firstname && $lastname && $email && $re_email && $password && $re_password && $age && $gender){}
    else{die("Please fill in all fields");}

    //USERNAME CHECKING//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $connect=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $database=mysql_select_db("phplogin", $connect);
    $namecheck=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($namecheck);
    if($count!=0)
    {die("Username already taken");}
```

here are Html code

```
<html>
<H1>Register</H1>
    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?PHP echo $firstname;?>" maxlength="25"/></td>
            <td>Maxium 25 characters</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?PHP echo $lastname;?>"maxlength="25"/></td>
            <td>Maxium 25 characters</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?PHP echo $email;?>"maxlength="40"/></td>
            <td>Maxium 40 characters</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Re-enter email:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="re_email" value="<?PHP echo $re_email;?>"maxlength="40"/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="25"/></td>
            <td>Password must be between 6 and 25 characters</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Re-eneter Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="re_password" maxlength="50"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <select>
            <option value="">Age</option>
            <option name="age" value="18-29">18-29</option>
            <option name="age" value="30-39">30-39</option>
            <option name="age" value="40-49">40-49</option>
            <option name="age" value="50-59">50-59</option>
            <option name="age" value="60-69">60-69</option>
            <option name="age" value="70">70 Plus</option>
        </select>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register" />
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: "the error I got are $age and $gender" What does this mean?

Comment: $namecheck=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable error reporting, add to your page:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

To allow error reporting to all pages, add to php.ini:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

and restart the Apache service.

Change toy select to :

```
<select name="age">
     <option value="18-29">18-29</option>
     <option value="30-39">30-39</option>
     <option value="40-49">40-49</option>
     <option value="50-59">50-59</option>
     <option value="60-69">60-69</option>
     <option value="70">70 Plus</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code from register.php beneath your form 
and put the form action to be the same page, 
then you will be able to display errors on the same page

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your HTML, for your SELECT, you need to set the "name" on the SELECT, not on the OPTIONS.

Comment: Then you have 2 solutions : set a default value in your INPUT radio by adding "checked" or "checked='checked'" (not the same depending of your doctype) _ or _ check in your PHP if it exists "if( isset($_POST['gender'] ) ..."